# String formatting %02d not performing as expected? What would cause the following code to not print truncated two-digit form? 

Tags: python, string, time, formatting

No clue why this is happening. I must be missing something obvious.

I'm trying to make a counter print out something like SMPTE code (hours:minutes:seconds:frames (assuming 24fps)).

Code thus far:

```
import time


s_time = time.time()
def format_time():
    t = time.time() - s_time 
    if t < 1:
        print '00:00:00:%02d' % int(t/0.041666666666666664)
    elif t < 60:
        t = str(t).split('.')

        print '00:00:%02d:%02d' % (int(t[0]), int(int(t[1][:4])/0.041666666666666664) )

while True:
    format_time()
```

All seems well initially, until the duration surpasses 1 second and the `elif` branch is entered. Seconds print out fine, but the frames print out the full multi-digit result of the calculation. Given that the formatting operator is specifying `%02d`, just like it does in the first `if` branch (which behaves as expected), why is it not obeying in the second branch? I'm at a loss trying to figure out why it is still printing the full result rather than the truncated version.

Comment: I think you want a `% 60` or `% 100` somewhere in there. (`%` as the modulus operator. try         `print '00:00:%02d:%02d' % (int(t[0]), int(int(t[1][:4])/0.041666666666666664) % 100 )`
)

Comment: Instead of `t/0.041666666666666664`, why not `t * 24.0`? Simpler, easier to write, and it's much more obvious where the number comes from (frames per second).

Comment: @Karl Knechtel - I'm not a clever man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get the integer part and the fractional part of the float to print your result. It is a good practice to use operators and functions on numeric data directly instead of adding a heavy overhead by converting the float into str and back to number.

Use the math module modf function for that. It will also simplify your algorithm.

```
import time
import math

s_time = time.time()
def format_time():
    t = time.time() - s_time
    if t < 60:
        f,i = math.modf(t)
        print '00:00:%02d:%02d' % (i, f/0.041666666666666664)

while True:
    format_time()
```

PS: for your code error, in your elif block, you are passing t as an integer with a huge value instead of passing the 0.xxxxx value of it. This error wouldn't occur if you keep using the math functions of floats.

Answer (score 2):

I expect you want something like this:

```
hours = int(t)/3600
minutes = (int(t)/60)%60
seconds = int(t)%60
frames = (t-int(t))*24
print '%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d' % (hours, minutes, seconds, frames)
```

Comment: This actually works quite well! And it remarkably simpler than this multi-if/else monster I was creating. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`%02d` means: print the integer and if it's shorter than 2 digits, prefix it with zeroes.
it doesn't limit the formatted string to two digits.

edit: one way of getting the first 2 (rounded) digits of a number `n` would be:

```
n = 13900
print round(n/10**math.floor(math.log10(n)-1))
```

or if you don't care about rounding, just cut the string...

Comment: .....Oh, crap. Embarrassing. I have completely misunderstood. Do you know of a formatting operator that accomplishes what I'm attempting to do?